# JQuery not removing active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my links slide down over the page when the mobile nav is clicked and the content to disappear so only the links are shown. I have got this basically working but the .displayNone class will not remove when I click the mobilenav again and I'm a bit dumfounded as to why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hamburger').on('click', function(){
      $('.links').slideToggle(200);
      var status = $('.wrapper').hasClass('.displayNone');
      if(status){ $('.wrapper').removeClass('.displayNone'); }
      else { $('.wrapper').addClass('displayNone'); }
    });

  });
```

Bit of newbie to all this. Anything obvious that anyone can see wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass()`,

```
$('.wrapper').toggleClass('displayNone');
```

And, jQuery's `xxxClass()` functions expect the name of the class, not the selector, so leave off the `.` class selector.

Answer (score 0):

When adding/removing classes, just use `displayNone`, not `.displayNone` (note the dot!).

Also there's a [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function which saves you from doing the `status` thing, which means you just need to do

```
$('.wrapper').toggleClass('displayNone');
```

Answer (score 0):

your are doing bit wrong

```
var status = $('.wrapper').hasClass('.displayNone');
```

when you use `hasClass, addClass or removeClass` then you don't need to have '.' dot before class name.

so correct way is

```
var status = $('.wrapper').hasClass('displayNone');
```

your code after correction

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hamburger').on('click', function() {
    $('.links').slideToggle(200);
    var status = $('.wrapper').hasClass('displayNone');
    if (status) {
      $('.wrapper').removeClass('displayNone');
    } else {
      $('.wrapper').addClass('displayNone');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$('.wrapper').toggleClass("displayNone");
```

Final code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#hamburger').on('click', function(){

        $('.links').slideToggle(200);

        $('.wrapper').toggleClass("displayNone");

    })

})
```